# Linear Relationship of $\mathcal{L}(6\cdot P)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I don't exactly see what is $\mathcal{L}(n\cdot P)$  Based on [the following answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294644/basis-for-the-riemann-roch-space-lkp-on-a-curve), I checked what is exaclty generated $L(n\cdot P)$. But I am still confusing... To being with,

- $l(0)=1$ :  a constant function in $\mathcal{L}(0)$
- $l(1\cdot  P)=1$ : a constant function in $\mathcal{L}(1\cdot P)$
- $l(2\cdot  P)=1$ : $x$, a pole of order 2 in $\mathcal{L}(2 \cdot P)$
- ...
- $l(6\cdot  P)=6$ : $x^2,y^3$  in $\mathcal{L}(6 \cdot P)$

[image]

And the following answer

- $\mathcal{L}(1\cdot P)=<1>, \mathcal{L}(2\cdot P)=<1,1/x>, ....  \mathcal{L}(4\cdot P)=<1, 1/x, 1/x^2, y/x^2 > $

**First**, when I comparing to the [the following answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294644/basis-for-the-riemann-roch-space-lkp-on-a-curve), I cannot understand why $\mathcal{L}(2\cdot P) $
is spanned by $1$ and $1/x$. Obviously my thought will be refuted, I think that $\mathcal{L}(2\cdot P) $ is spanned by $1$, "$1/x^2$", simply because pole of order "$2$". If $1/x$, it seems to have a pole of order "$1$"

**Second**, why this step stops when $n=6$? Just because of to construct elliptic curve? and I cannot also understand why $7$ functions in $6$ dimension space has a deep relation between the following functions :
$$ay^2+by+cxy=dx^3+ex^2+fx+g......(★)$$
Maybe I think that $L(6\cdot P)= <1,1/x,1/x^2,y/x^2,?,?>$ and $\mathcal{L}(6\cdot P) $ contains the following terms : constant,$x,y,x^2,xy,y^2$, and $x^3$, according to the above graph. But when I consider the basis of $\mathcal{L}(6\cdot P)$, it is strange why $(★)$ abruptly pops.. each terms that I mentioned is in numerator and denominator-- for example $y/x^2$ , the term $y$ is in numerator, while $x^2$ is in denominator.

**Edit : Notation**

Let $D$ be a divisor

- $\mathcal{L}(D):=\left\{f \in K(C) : (f)=\sum_{p}ord_p(f) P \ge -D \right\}$
- $\mathcal{L}(n\cdot P ):=\left\{f \in K(C) : (f)=\sum_{p}ord_p(f) P \ge -n\cdot P \right\}$
- $l(D):= \dim \mathcal{L}(D)$

(or, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551117/what-is-a-basis-of-ld-on-the-riemann-roch-theorem) is the link that I asked previously)

Comment: What is $\mathcal{L}$, where is it defined etc…? Add definitions

Comment: This is a mess. What is the actual original problem you're trying to solve? Between this and your [other recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551117/what-is-a-basis-of-ld-on-the-riemann-roch-theorem), it seems like you're running in to an instance of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - asking about your proposed solution instead of your underlying issue.